# Search and page size selection with jQuery Datatable disappear on postback

Tags: jquery, asp.net, datatables

I am using a Query datatable, wrapping a bootstrap-styled table. Rows are populated using .net repeater control. 
Initially, both search text box and page size selection dropdown are displayed. When i cause a postback, data in table is updated but search textbox and page size selection dropddown disappear.

This is in .aspx:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="upnlPC" RenderMode="Block">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div runat="server" id="divTRP" style="display:block">
            <table id="fcTRPTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-responsive">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Area</th>
                        <th>District</th>
                        <th>Plant</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>

                <tbody>
                    <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptTRPTableData">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <tr>
                                <td runat="server" id="tdArea"><%# Eval("Area") %></td>
                                <td runat="server" id="tdDistrict"><%# Eval("District") %></td>
                                <td runat="server" id="tdFacility"><%# Eval("Plant") %></td>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:Repeater>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // DataTable, save state
        var adminUsersDT = $('#fcTRPTable').DataTable({
            'bDestroy':true,
            "bStateSave": true,
            dom: 'lfrtip',
            "fnStateSave": function (oSettings, oData) {
                localStorage.setItem('fcTRPTable', JSON.stringify(oData));
            },
            "fnStateLoad": function (oSettings) {
                return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('fcTRPTable'));
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

in .aspx, page_load():

```
DataTable dtVD = someBLL.GiveMeTableData();
rptTRPTableData.DataSource = dtVD;
rptTRPTableData.DataBind();
```

**Solution**

The problem with initial issue was the fact that the data table was inside an update panel. It had nothing to do with search textbox or page size selection drop down; the entire jQuery data table would not redraw.

The solution for me was this (added the following javascript code):

```
$(function () {
    bindDataTable(); // bind data table on first page load
    // bind data table on every UpdatePanel refresh
    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(bindDataTable);
});

function bindDataTable() {
    var adminUsersDT = $('#fcTable').DataTable({
        'bDestroy': true,
        "bStateSave": true,
        dom: 'lfrtip',
        "fnStateSave": function (oSettings, oData) {
            localStorage.setItem('fcTable', JSON.stringify(oData));
        },
        "fnStateLoad": function (oSettings) {
            return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('fcTable'));
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I realized it is not just the search and page size selection that disappear; the entire jQuery datatabe goes away. I lose all the jQuery Datatable functionality. Not sure how to reconstruct the datatable on reload.

Comment: I noticed the problem was caused by table being inside an update panel and jQuery script outside of it. Partial postback did not force the script to run again. If I remove the update panel it works fine. Any idea on how to have the update panel and jQuery Datatable both? Moving the script inside update panel did not help either.

Answer (score 0):

I posted the solution for my problem in edited question above; hope it will help someone save a few hours of time and a few strands of hair.